# Google Chrome Developer Tools : "Step Over Next Function Call"

Tags: google-chrome

Basically, I clearly don't understand how to use this.

I want to re-open a windows of 16 tabs. Because I closed a few items since then, it is no longer on the "Recently closed list".

I managed to track down the script that deletes "extra" items - Line 1884 & 1885

```
elementsToHide.forEach(function(el) {
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```

So, I set breakpoints for these and when I resized the window, it fired and showed **ALL** the recent items, but everything was disabled as the debugger was running - I tried *Step over next function call*, which I thought should of done it, however, it deleted the items straight away.

I tried the other two with no luck.

So, Did I miss understand this command, Did I do it wrong or is it not working correctly?

And most importantly, what can I do to disable this part of the script (at the moment, I am thinking of hooking up my 1080p TV to give the window a higher resolution and display more items!)

... !Bonus section!, but not vital...

Before I found the two lines above (which I think is the best solution) I first found the section that looks up and saves the screen resolution to a variable. I changed the variable straight after it was called, however, the moment I resume the script, the variable got changed back - without anything calling it. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you misunderstood.  Step over doesn't mean, "Don't execute the function."  It just tells the debugger not to debug each line in the function separately.

Comment: Ok - well, makes perfect sense! Is there anyway I can skip it - using the console or otherwise?